# 90 day limit for visa waiver program

Tags: visas, usa, international-travel, uk-citizens

I am a British citizen and have been travelling here in the USA, basically when I booked my return flight I wanted to get the full 90 days’ worth but I miscalculated by one too many days. I'm set to return to the UK on the 5th when I am legally obliged to do so on the 4th. It’s going to cost me some money to get that changed, but I was already planning to visit some friends who are currently living in Colombia, then returning back to the US.

Will this trip restart my ESTA time and therefore mean I won’t have to change my return flight?

Comment: so, it applies to any country not on that list?

Comment: @user27542 correct.  Exiting to Mexico, Canada and that list of small Caribbean places, doesn't reset it, but others do.

Comment: Also be aware that US immigration can deny you entry if they think you are trying to 'game the system'. I doubt you will have any trouble, especially if you are in Colombia for more than a couple of days. But in general even a visit to a country not on the list doesn't *guarantee* you another 90 day stay.

Comment: ok thanks alot, very handy to know - i suppose the fact that i have a return flight already booked will clear things up - sorry to keep asking but how iwll i know whether my stay has been reset? will they notify me on arriving back in the states?

Comment: The stamp in your passport should also have the date by which you must depart the US. When you return from Colombia you will get a new stamp and a new departure date.

Comment: @DJClayworth also, it's unlikely that anyone would care about or look for evidence of gaming the system when the potential overstay is by one day.